# Joining two tables by multiple fields in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have two tables.  One lists my store's Customer Number, The Item They Bought, The Date They Bought It, and the Price They Paid.

I have a second table that lists my store's Customer Number, The Item They Returned, The Date They Returned It, and the Credit They Received.

Obviously, not all Sales have Credits.

I want to return results that look like:

```
Customer1, Item1, Date, Price, Blank
Customer1, Item2, Date, Price, Credit
Customer1, Item3, Date, Price, Blank
Customer1, Item4, Date, Price, Blank
Customer2, Item1, Date, Price, Blank
Customer2, Item2, Date, Price, Blank
Customer2, Item3, Date, Price, Credit
```

etc.

If I join the tables on the Customer Number, it returns me:

```
Customer1, Item1, Date, Price, Credit
Customer1, Item2, Date, Price, Credit
Customer1, Item3, Date, Price, Credit
Customer1, Item4, Date, Price, Credit
Customer2, Item1, Date, Price, Credit
Customer2, Item2, Date, Price, Credit
Customer2, Item3, Date, Price, Credit
```

If I join the tables on the Item and sort by Customer number, it returns gobbledygook.

My idea was to join on the Customer number and use an `IIf(Sales.Item1=Credits.Item1, Credit, 0)` in the criteria, but I am getting an error "You tried to execute a query ... that is not part of an aggregate expression."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What would I change the Group By pulldown to?  None of the other options seem applicable.

Comment: Getting rid of the Sigma gets rid of the error, but the query is still returning junk.

Comment: I did resolve the issue.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you, Don! (The answer was not from me, but it is good to see people rewarded here).

Comment: No, thank you for all of your help!  I apologize that I haven't logged into SO for awhile.  I'm a business analyst and I work contractually for many clients through an agency.  I had a couple weeks off between clients.  But now, back to the grind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you will have no *returns* without  *Sales*, try this Query:

```
SELECT Sales.Customer, Sales.Item, Sales.Sale_Date, Sales.Sale_Price, 
   Credits.Credit_Date, Credits.Credit_Price, 
   IIf(IsDate([Credits].[Credit_Date]),"Credit","Blank") AS Result 
   FROM Sales LEFT JOIN Credits ON (Sales.Customer = Credits.Customer) 
   AND (Sales.Item = Credits.Item);
```

Define your values in the IIF statement (*Credit* or *Blank*) as needed.
You also can hide your fields Credits.Credit_Date, Credits.Credit_Price, so the output will be exactly what desired.